# Hacer que el contador no se detenga

Tags: c#, bucle-for, consola

Espero y se encuentren muy bien.
Espero no importunar con mi problema, pero he buscado solución alguna y no sé qué hacer.
Lo que pasa con el código es que, a la hora de ejecutarlo, el "Readline" se repite a la par del bucle "for", lo que provoca que el timer se detenga y el "input" se repita mientras el ciclo "for" esté activo.

Sé que esto se debe a que el "readline" está dentro del mismo bucle, pero el inconveniente es que no sé qué se pueda hacer para ejecutar el timer que está en el código y que el programa, al mismo tiempo, pueda recibir la entrada de datos. Como pueden ver en el código, es una especie de "juego" que estoy intentando hacer, pero soy muy novato en el tema, por eso he decidido venir a pedir de su ayuda.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Prueba_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int puntos = 0;
            int vidas = 3;
            int result;

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cuánto es (5^2)-(-5^2)");
            for (int a = 3; a >= 0; a--)
                {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                Console.Title = "¡Quedan " + a + " segundos!";
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Respuesta: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
                
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                if (a == 0)
                {
                    vidas = -1 ;
                    Console.Title = "Vidas: " + vidas + "." + "    " + "Puntaje: " + puntos;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("El tiempo se ha acabado, colega. Se ha restado 1 punto. u.u");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
                  Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar dos procesos distintos para ejecutar cosas en paralelo. Échale un ojo a la clase [Thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

puedes utilizar un hilo distinto para preguntarle al usuario la tecla y así no bloquear el hilo principal, te he hecho un pequeño ejemplo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Creamos el task para leer de consola para asi no bloquear el hilo principal y usar otro hilo para leer de consola
            var tarea= LeerDeConsola;

            
            for (int i=0 ;i<3 ;i++ )
            {
                // Inicializamos key como default
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = default;
                if ( key!=default )
                {
                    
                    // TODO: Aqui haces lo que quieras con tu key 
                }
                if ( tarea.IsCompleted )
                {
                    // Si la tarea se completo extraemos el key y volvemos a inicializarla

                    key=tarea.Result;
                    tarea=LeerDeConsola;


                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
            }

        }

    private static Task<ConsoleKeyInfo>  LeerDeConsola => Task<ConsoleKeyInfo>.Run
                (( ) =>
                {

                    return Console.ReadKey( );
                });
```

Mucha suerte con tu juego